# traer columna completa de codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter

hola comunidad saben como puedo traer los datos completos de una columna
ya que este es mi modelo pero solo me traer un dato

```
public function getCantidadAsignadaUser()
    {
        $this->db->select('fechatermino ');
        $this->db->from('eusuarios');
        $row = $this->db->get()->row();
                 return $row->fechatermino  ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para **Codeigniter 3** es necesario que utilices `->get()->result_object()`, porque al hacer uso de `->get()->row()` solo estás obteniendo el primer resultado.

También puedes utilizar `->get()->result_array()`, la diferencia es que con `_array()` te retorna un arreglo asociativo `$arr[]` y con `_object()` te retorna un arreglo de objetos `$arr->`.

Puedes ver la [documentación oficial](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html) para que veas las distintas opciones que tienes disponibles para tus consultas.